# Ubntu 18.04 trackpoint feels weird and squishy

Tags: 18.04, thinkpad, trackpoint

I've just upgraded from 16.04 to 18.04 and my trackpoint started to feel really weird. The movement seems to be really squishy and uneven, but I can't quite tell what the problem is. I've played with the sensitivity and acceleration settings, but that doesn't seem to help that much. When I use the USB mouse from my dock, everything seems to work fine, it's just the trackpoint. Working on a Thinkpad X250.

Answer (score 0):

You must install the synaptics mouse driver.

Comment: Thanks adsa for your answer, but can you explain how he can do that  ?